# How to send TextBox contents as an email body?

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am trying to send an email by pressing a button. Everything works fine other than the body of the email. It always shows up blank. The body is being typed into TextBox1 (NOT User Form). I was hoping that putting it in a textbox would format it when sending the email.

```
Sub Email()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim ChartName As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    ChartName = Environ$("temp") & "\Chart4.gif"
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Send Email").ChartObjects("Chart 4").Chart.Export _
        Filename:=ChartName, FilterName:="GIF"

    With OutMail
        .To = Range("A2")
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Range("A4")

        '.body is the only thing not working it always shows up blank
        .Body = Worksheets("Send Email").TextBox1.Value
        .Attachments.Add ChartName
        .Display 'will use send when working

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Kill ChartName
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Much easier to debug without `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Try `.Body = Worksheets("Send Email").TextBox1.Text`